Pandas Dataframe check relation of variable and rolling mean
I have a DataFrame df with one time series variable, call it X.
I can find the rolling mean over the last (say) n observations with
df['rolling_mean'] = df.X.rolling(window=n).mean()

Now I want a new column with a boolean value that applies the following logic to each row and returns true if either:

X > rolling_mean and sometime within the next k observations, X attains a value less than rolling_mean
or X < rolling_mean and sometime within the next k observations, X attains a value greater than rolling_mean.

My current workaround looks something like:
new_column = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    next_k = df[i:i + k]
    if row.X < row.rolling_mean and any(next_k.X > row.rolling_mean):
        new_column.append(1)
    elif row.X > row.rolling_mean and any(next_k.X < row.rolling_mean):
        new_column.append(1)
    else:
        new_column.append(0)

df['new_column'] = new_column

But obviously this is iterative and not fast enough for a large dataset.
Is there a fast/vectorized way of doing this?

A nice solution I came up with:
df['rolling_max'] = df.X.rolling(k, min_periods=0).max().shift(-k)
df['rolling_min'] = df.X.rolling(k, min_periods=0).min().shift(-k)

df['will_drop_below_mean'] = (df.X > df.rolling_mean) & (df.rolling_min < df.rolling_mean)
df['will_rise_above_mean'] = (df.X < df.rolling_mean) & (df.rolling_max > df.rolling_mean)

df['new_column'] = ((df._will_drop_below_mean) | (df._will_rise_above_mean)).astype(int)

Basically using rolling().max() and rolling().min() with .shift() to create two boolean masks.

I'd consider using numba to speed up the task, e.g.:
from numba import njit


@njit
def get_value(X, rolling_mean, out, k):
    for i, (x, rm) in enumerate(zip(X, rolling_mean)):
        if x < rm:
            for idx in range(i, min(i + k, len(out))):
                if X[idx] > rm:
                    out[i] = 1
                    break
        elif x > rm:
            for idx in range(i, min(i + k, len(out))):
                if X[idx] < rm:
                    out[i] = 1
                    break


df["new_column"] = 0
get_value(df.X.values, df.rolling_mean.values, df.new_column.values, 3)


Test
n = 5
k = 3

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": np.random.randint(1, 100, size=20)})
df["rolling_mean"] = df.X.rolling(window=n).mean()


new_column = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    next_k = df[i : i + k]
    if row.X < row.rolling_mean and any(next_k.X > row.rolling_mean):
        new_column.append(1)
    elif row.X > row.rolling_mean and any(next_k.X < row.rolling_mean):
        new_column.append(1)
    else:
        new_column.append(0)

df["new_column"] = new_column
df["new_column_2"] = 0
get_value(df.X.values, df.rolling_mean.values, df.new_column_2.values, 3)

print(df)

Prints:
     X  rolling_mean  new_column  new_column_2
0   52           NaN           0             0
1   93           NaN           0             0
2   15           NaN           0             0
3   72           NaN           0             0
4   61          58.6           1             1
5   21          52.4           1             1
6   83          50.4           0             0
7   87          64.8           0             0
8   75          65.4           0             0
9   75          68.2           1             1
10  88          81.6           1             1
11  24          69.8           0             0
12   3          53.0           0             0
13  22          42.4           1             1
14  53          38.0           1             1
15   2          20.8           1             1
16  88          33.6           1             1
17  30          39.0           0             0
18  38          42.2           0             0
19   2          32.0           0             0


Benchmark
from timeit import timeit

n = 5
k = 3

df = pd.DataFrame({"X": np.random.randint(1, 100, size=1_000_000)})
df["rolling_mean"] = df.X.rolling(window=n).mean()

def method_original(df, k):
    new_column = []
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        next_k = df[i : i + k]
        if row.X < row.rolling_mean and any(next_k.X > row.rolling_mean):
            new_column.append(1)
        elif row.X > row.rolling_mean and any(next_k.X < row.rolling_mean):
            new_column.append(1)
        else:
            new_column.append(0)

    df["new_column"] = new_column


def method_numba(df, k):
    df["new_column"] = 0
    get_value(df.X.values, df.rolling_mean.values, df.new_column.values, 3)


t1 = timeit("method_original(x, 3)", setup="x=df.copy()", number=1, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit("method_numba(x, 3)", setup="x=df.copy()", number=1, globals=globals())

print(t1)
print(t2)

Prints on my computer AMD 5700x:
82.54220866700052
0.008329503005370498

So quite nice speed-up.
